Overwrite micronaut default JWTAuthentication to provide custom implementation
My microservices uses X-XSRF-TOKEN instead of authorization and bearer to pass token, I am changing few of my services to micronaut, but i couldn't figure out how to use my style of passing the token information to validate jwt
Here is my sample curl request
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/endpoint/action' \
--header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJiYW5rIjoiSE9TVCIsInJvbGUiOiJiZGZmNjBmNDRhYmE0MzIzODM5OWI3N2U5NDc4OGMxMSIsIkRFUExPWU1FTlRfTkFNRVNQQUNFIjoic2VydmljZS1zdGFnaW5nIiwiZnVsbE5hbWUiOiJmaXJzdG5hbWUgbGFzdG5hbWUiLCJhZ2VuY3lDb2RlIjoiIiwib3BlcmF0b3JDb2RlIjoiIiwiTEFTVC1BQ0NFU1MtVElNRSI6IjE3MTI3NDk5Mjg5MTgiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImZpcnN0bmFtZWxhc3RuYW1lQEdNQUlMLkNPTSIsImV4cCI6MTcxMjc1MDUyOH0.lH2gGiTkzg5pPo7mp7dhBaMwbpYTTR7YmGysrWJYcyk'

Here is my yaml implementation for security
        token:
            csrf:
                enabled: true
            bearer:
                enabled: false
                header-name: X-XSRF-TOKEN
            jwt:
                signatures:
                    secret:
                        generator:
                            secret: "${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET:eefe82f8-7ca6-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003}"

Is there a way i can overwrite the existing implementation of jwtvalidation and register it as a bean so that authentication would pass through my custom implementation

I got the solution, had to implement the TokenValidator class
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable;
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.Authentication;
import io.micronaut.security.token.validator.TokenValidator;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Collections;


public class JwtTokenValidation<B> implements TokenValidator<B> {
    @Override
    public Publisher<Authentication> validateToken(String token, @Nullable B request) {
        // Validation implementation  
        return Mono.just(Authentication.build("username", Collections.emptyList()));
    }
}

Here is yaml file setting, if anyone else needs a similar implementation
        token:
            bearer:
                header-name: X-XSRF-TOKEN
                prefix: ''

